# Get from mysql table where multiple id in one cell

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table invoices:

```
    id|orders|user|status|
    1 |1,2,5 |1   |1     |
    2 |75    |2   |0     |
    3 |31,4  |5   |1     |
```

What should be my request to the database so that I receive the invoice status by the order number in the orders column.

It seems to me that the way to use LIKE here is not suitable as it will select incorrect values.

```
    $sql = "SELECT status FROM invoices WHERE orders LIKE '%".$order_id."%'";
```

Comment: You normalize the table and stop saving multiple values on same field.

Comment: Agree with Juan.  You're setting yourself up for a coding nightmare doing it that way.  One value per row is the standard.

Comment: Also use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
 $sql = "SELECT status 
         FROM invoices 
         WHERE CONCAT(',', orders, ',') LIKE '%,".$order_id.",%'";
```

Comment: For some reason, it does not always give the correct value.

Comment: What cases doesn't found the correct value? do you have spaces on the orders string?

Comment: No, I dont have spaces. For ex. cant find any id from this "605,604,415,367,339,338" but can find from this "512,511" or from this "19". Mystic The same with the query that was written by Florent above

Comment: Also for some reason if i searching status form order_id 250 it returns 1, but real status is 0

Comment: Can you be more precise. What is the id you are looking and what are the orders on the db. because if you are looking for multiple id, you wont be able to do it. And 19 isnt on that list

Comment: I tried run that query from phpmyadmin and it works correctly. But when I run with php at my page it work not correctly.

Comment: Then you problem is the php. I just give you the working query

Comment: Yes, I will mark your answer correct. I will look for the problem myself. Thank.

Comment: Still you should consider normalize your db, That will save you headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this assuming no space is used

```
$sql =<<<REQQ
SELECT status 
FROM invoices 
WHERE orders LIKE '{$order_id}'
OR orders LIKE '{$order_id},%'
OR orders LIKE '%,{$order_id},%'
OR orders LIKE '%,{$order_id}'
REQQ;
//end
```